# Inner join in Linq with more than 2 datatables

Tags: linq, datatable

i have 3 tables

t1==>

```
 t1.ID    t1.co1     t1.col2

 1       a         b              
 2       a         b
```

t2==>

```
 t2.ID    t2.co1     t2.col2

  1       a         b              
  2       a         b
```

t3==>

```
 t3.ID    t3.co1     t3.col2

 1       a         b              
 2       a         b
```

i want inner join between all three tables using Linq and want selected column in 4th datatable.

equivalent sql query:

```
SELECT t1.ID,t2.col1,t3.col2 
  FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.ID=t3.ID
```

t4==>

```
 t1.ID    t2.co1     t3.col2

 1        a         b              
 2        a         b
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
var Result = 
    from row1 in t1
    join row2 in t2 on row1.ID equals row2.ID
    join row3 in t3 on row1.ID equals row3.ID
    select new { ID = row1.ID, Col1 = row2.col1, Col2 = row3.col2 }

DataTable dt = Result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: haste makes waste)) Thanks

Comment: @voo: thanks for ur reply :). i did almost same but how can i convert var Result to datatable?

Comment: @WebDevelopmentHurricane, check my answer, you need to use `CopyToDataTable()` method.

Comment: ...but honestly, *you don't want to use a DataTable*.  Like, ever :-).

Answer (score 1):

Use `LoadDataRow()` to get a DataTable from an *`anonymous`* type as [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/6d4e2579-f4b5-497c-ad00-7c347eb1f902). Else `Result.CopyToDataTable()`.

```
//Get the column list as same as table1 to new datatable
DataTable table4 = table1.Clone();

var Result = 
  from x in t1.AsEnumerable() join 
       y in t2.AsEnumerable() on x.Field<int>("ID") equals y.Field<int>("ID") join 
       z in t3.AsEnumerable() on x.Field<int>("ID") equals z.Field<int>("ID")
  select new table4.LoadDataRow( 
       new object[] { 
              x.ID, 
              y.col1, 
              z.col2 
           }, false);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for selecting "Selected Columns". select x).CopyToDataTable(); it  works fine but when  new { 
       ID = x.ID, 
       col1 = y.col1, 
       col2 = z.col2 
  }.CopyToDataTable();    -- it doesn't